# How to use For loop in Javascript, like Each loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's very easy to use Each loop in jQuery. But I want to use For loop in JS, without using jQuery.

I can use Each loop like this. And `$(this)` selector is very helpful to reach child elements.

```
$('.documents .document.selected').each(function(index){
    console.log($(this).find('.document-name p').text())//this code gives me all selected element's name
})
```

I want to reach child elements by using For loop, but this code doesn't even works...

```
for (let i = 0; i < $('.documents .document.selected').length; i++) {
    console.log($('.documents .document.selected')[i].find('.document-name p').text())//but this is not
}
```

I want to use For loop by using `$(this)` selector, but it's not working with For loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < $('.documents .document.selected').length; i++) {
    console.log($(this).find('.document-name p').text())
}
```

How to use For loop very easy as I show you or do you have any suggest?

Comment: Without using jQuery… but you’re still using `$(…)` to perform the selection.

Comment: You are right. I meant half JS, half jQuery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because accessing an array-index property on an jQuery collection gives you the native DOM element in return, not a jQuery collection containing the element.

```
$('.documents .document.selected')[i].find
```

should be

```
$('.documents .document.selected').eq(i).find
```

But that's still using jQuery. If you want to avoid jQuery completely, you need to remove all references to `$`. Try:

```
const selectedDocs = document.querySelectorAll('.documents .document.selected');
for (let i = 0; i < selectedDocs.length; i++) {
    console.log(selectedDocs[i].querySelector('.document-name p').textContent);
}
```

Or avoid manual iteration and invoke the iterator instead:

```
for (const selectedDoc of document.querySelectorAll('.documents .document.selected')) {
    console.log(selectedDoc.querySelector('.document-name p').textContent);
}
```

`querySelector` is the vanilla DOM method equivalent of jQuery's `.find`.

Comment: `selectedDocuments.eq(i).find('.document-name p').text()` works as I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: That's still using jQuery - and you said you didn't want to use any jQuery, right?

Comment: I meant half JS, half jQuery but you are right. I wanted to use JS because my codes didn't work and I thought there is no way to use For loop with jQuery until I see the `eq(i)`